# Gnome doesn't store password in keyring

Tags: gnome, keyrings, pam

I'm on 12.04, trying to extract my login credintials from ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring and not having much luck, looks like that keyring is empty. seahorse is showing it as an empty keystore. I tried deleting it but it gets re-created upon login while still remains empty.

pam configs do seem to call keyring daemon:

```
$ grep keyring /etc/pam.d/*
common-password:password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so 
gdm:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
gdm:session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
gnome-screensaver:auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
lightdm:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
lightdm:session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

No, your local system password is not stored in the keyring. The `login` keyring will remain empty until you authenticate to some service in an application which stores passwords or tokens in the keyring. The `pam` integration is to allow keeping the login passowrd, and your keyring password, in sync, and to allow unlocking the keyring automatically, when you log in.